# How to build Vue components as a library for Nuxtjs with SSR support?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, babeljs, monorepo

I have two packages in a monorepo environment,

1. A nuxtjs app.
2. A Vue 2 components library.

I'm trying to build the components package as a ["Library"](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#library) so that I can import the components in the Nuxt app.

After building-installing-importing the library, the nuxt raises the following error:

```sh
document is not defined
```

inside the library build

```js
function o(e) {
  var t, n, i = document.querySelector('style[data-vue-ssr-id~="' + e.id + '"]');
  if (i) {
    if (f) return g;
    i.parentNode.removeChild(i)
  }
  if (m) {
```

I get that it's because nuxt is encountering the browser's `document` object when it's attempting to render the page on the server-side.

Just a thought, is it because I'm using in-component styles?

It'd be great if someone could confirm it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to create a full Vue SSR library, you can follow this very useful [guide](https://ssr.vuejs.org/).

Otherwhise you can tell Nuxt to load your library only on client side in this way:

1. In your Nuxt application create the file `plugins/my-vue-library-plugin.js`
2. Fill it with this content for import your Vue component library:

   ```
   import Vue from 'vue'
   import MyLibrary from 'my-vue-library-path'

   Vue.use(MyLibrary)
   ```
3. Then add the file path inside the `plugins` key of our `nuxt.config.js`

   ```
    export default {
      plugins: [
        { src: '~/plugins/my-vue-library-plugin.js', mode: 'client' }
      ]
    }
   ```

How you can see the `mode: 'client'` property is the key because tells Nuxt to load the library only on client side, so your `document is not defined` error should disappear.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that's what I'm already doing. Is it possible to build the component library with SSR support

Comment: I updated my question so that the context is better understood.

Comment: Can you provide some resource where it guides how to bundle a components library for SSR and can I use the same library for both CSR and SSR apps?